# how to map inside a map in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this *"data"* object that already map and I need to mapping the *cmsmenuschild* and put it at *"children:[]"* because it has data array of object too and I want to change the *cmsmenuschild* payload *id* and *name* to be *key* and *title* , like I just done to id and name before.
I really new  at React so I,m still figuring out how to do the map inside a map like this.any help would be appreciate

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);          
    this.state = {
                listMenu: []
        };
    }

       data = [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Manage User",
                        "cmsmenuschild": [
                                        {"id": 14,"name": "Create User"},
                                        {"id": 15,"name": "Update User"},
                        ]
                    },
                         {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Manage BTP",
                        "cmsmenuschild": [
                            {"id": 18,"name": "Create BTP"},
                            {"id": 19,"name": "Update BTP"},

                        ]
                    },
                ]


          const privilegesData = this.data.map((privilege) => {
                  return {
                      key: privilege.id,
                      title: privilege.name,
                      children:[{
                                key: privilege2.id,
                                title: privilege2.name,
}],
                  };
                });




    this.setState({
                      listMenu: privilegesData,
                    });
```

***expected to display new this.state.listMenu woudl be like this***

```
 this.state.listMenu : [
                        {
                            "key": 1,
                            "title": "Manage User",
                            "children": [
                                       {"key": 14,"title": "Create User"},
                                      {"key": 15,"title": "Update User"},
                            ]
                        },
                             {
                            "key": 2,
                            "key": "Manage BTP",
                            "children": [
                                {"key": 18,"title": "Create BTP"},
                                {"key": 19,"title": "Update BTP"},

                            ]
                        },
                    ]
```

Comment: In fact you don't even need to map over `cmsmenuschild`. Just use `privilege.cmsmenuschild` to have its array data in the `children` key.

Comment: I'm sorry I just edited My question , that's what I really mean to do because if 
 I just use privilege.cmsmenuschild it keep using the id and name payload and my goal is to change the payload to key and title as well@Oblosys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just map over the `cmsmenuschild` object array, like this:

```
data.map((privilege) => {
    return {
        key: privilege.id,
        title: privilege.name,
        children: privilege.cmsmenuschild.map(child => {
            return {keys: child.id, title: child.name}
        }),
    }
})
```

Comment: yap that's it ,that what I've been looking for. Thanks it work now

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to map again:

```
 const privilegesData = this.data.map((privilege) => {
     return {
         key: privilege.id,
         title: privilege.name,
         children: privilege.cmsmenuchild, // or [...privilege.cmsmenuchild] if your worried about mutability
     };
 });
```

**EDIT:** If you need to handle a recursive data structure with an arbitrary amount of children

```
const keyAndTitle = (obj) => ({ key: o.id, title: o.name });

const normalizeObj = (data) => data.map(d => {
   const obj = keyAndTitle(data);
   if (d.hasOwnProperty('cmsmenuchild')) {
    obj.children = normalizeObj(d.cmsmenuchild);
   }
   return obj;
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry I just edited my question , that's what I really mean to do because if I just use privilege.cmsmenuschild it keep using the id and name payload and my goal is to change the payload to key and title as well

Comment: could `cmsmenuchild` also have it's own `cmsmenuchild` property?